# Clean Urls with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

How do I make it so when a user clicks on,
http://localhost/jobwehave.co.za/job/1

They are shown the page for
http://localhost/jobwehave.co.za/job?=1

But the url still says
http://localhost/jobwehave.co.za/job/1

I am using mod_rewrite in an .htaccess file at the root of the site.

Comment: Hm, is this on-topic?  I don't think it every really was, no matter what the Related list says...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

RewriteRule ^jobwehave.co.za/job/(\d+)$ jobwehave.co.za/job?id=$1

Rick.

Comment: the only edit i had to make was escaping each / with a \ this was closest to the method i used to solve it thank you.

Comment: Ah sorry it was just off the top off my head, glad its working though!

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /jobwehave.co.za/job/([0-9]+)$ /jobwehave.co.za/job?job=$1 [L,QSA]
```